# Exponential Decay Problem

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I've spent over an hour researching Carbon-14 decay for a Calculus problem, but I have one main problem when solving them: how do you solve for the `k` value (decay constant)?

Here is the problem

> The method of carbon dating makes use of the fact that all living
>   organisms contain two isotopes of carbon, carbon-12, denoted 12C (a
>   stable isotope), and carbon-14, denoted 14C (a radioactive isotope).
>   The ratio of the amount of 14C to the amount of 12C is essentially
>   constant (approximately 1/10,000). When an organism dies, the amount
>   of 12C present remains unchanged, but the 14C decays at a rate
>   proportional to the amount present with a half-life of approximately
>   5700 years. This change in the amount of 14C relative to the amount of
>   12C makes it possible to estimate the time at which the organism
>   lived.
>
> **A fossil found in an archaeological dig was found to contain 20% of the original amount
>   of 14C. What is the approximate age of the fossil?**

So, I'm not completely lost. I'm aware that the equation I need is:

$$\frac{[\ln\frac{N}{No}]}{k} * t_{1/2}$$

And I find many websites that insert `-.693` for `k` when referencing Carbon-14 problems, but I have no idea why they use that value. I assume that the "approximately `1/10,000`" part of the problem is significant, but I don't understand why.

Can someone please help me with understanding how to calculate this `k` value that some places have as `-.693` and some sites have as `.0001...`, both referencing Carbon-14 problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not get the $-0.693$ value, but perhaps my answer will help anyway.

If we assume Carbon-14 decays continuously, then
$$
C(t) = C_0e^{-kt},
$$
where $C_0$ is the initial size of the sample. We don't know this value, but we don't need it. Since it takes 5,700 years for a sample to decay to half its size, we know
$$
\frac{1}{2} C_0 = C_0e^{-5700k},
$$
which means
$$
\frac{1}{2} = e^{-5700k},
$$
so the value of $C_0$ is irrelevant.

Now, take the logarithm of both sides to get
$$
-0.693 = -5700k,
$$
from which we can derive
$$
k \approx 1.22 \cdot 10^{-4}.
$$

Comment: Austin, thanks for the answer. Plugging that `k` value into my equation yields an incredibly large age (-9.17 * 10^7). Am I missing something here? Should I be using the first equation in your answer?

Comment: So either the answer is that ridiculously big number (9.17e7) or 30,476 years, being calculated with the equation I provided and the first equation in your answer, respectively. I'm leaning toward the latter.

Comment: Like you said, the equation I'm using was for a different type of problem. Thanks for your help! You made these kinds of problems incredibly simple!

Comment: please check your Math. It seems you calculated the natural log of `.5` to be -.301, which is incorrect. It seems to be `-.693`

Comment: @David You are correct. It appears I mistakenly hit the "log base 10" button on my calculator. Now the mystery is solved!